# Calendar is not getting shown

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show a calendar in my `HTML` page using `DatePicker()`. I have included the appropriate UI js files as well but still it is not showing me the calendar in the UI.
 Kindly help. I am not able to figure out where exactly I am making a mistake.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Project Information</title>
<script src="../jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#datePicker").datepicker();

});      

</script>


</head>
<body>

    <form action="/projects/1" method="post">
        <fieldset id="project_information">
            <legend>Project Infomation</legend>
            <ol>
                <li><label for="priority">Project Name</label> <input
                    type="text" id="projectName" autofocus="autofocus"></li>
                <li><label for="priority">Priority</label> <input type="range"
                    min="0" max="10" name="priority" value="0" id="priority"></li>
                <li><label for="start_date">Start date</label> <input
                    type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date"
                    placeholder="YYYY-DD-MM" id="datePicker">
                </li>  

                <li><input type="button" id="submit" value="clickMe"></li>
            </ol>

        </fieldset>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first <script src="../jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-ui.min.js"></script> dont add them both. any one.

Comment: Any errors in your console? Also, it's become standard practice to include script references and inline script at the end of the document rather than the head.

Comment: You forgot to include the stylesheet for jQueryUI?

Comment: any error in console? you have to check source code to confirm that all scripts are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 ids remove 1 it will work

```
 <input type="text" name="start_date"  placeholder="YYYY-DD-MM" id="datePicker"/>
```

remove `id="start_date".`

here is the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/nUvwf/1/

Comment: Thanks A Paul, I would like to know how u have added the libraries to the script in fiddle. any steps?

Comment: you mean jquery libraries right? to select that in the left side of the fiddle you have to select jquery 1.8 and then check the jquery.ui. Jquery UI has them. If this answer is correct dont forget to mark it as correct:)

Comment: Let me put it this way. If I want to add jquery I should go and select jquery and it will give me options to check whatever I need. then if I also want to use knockout or angular or something else, if I will select that then the already selected jquery options are not checked. So how can I select multiple libraries?